# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

trying to insert data in database but it's return that error and the date format I am trying to add in this format example : 20/05/2015

my code :

```
 bool flag = gh.Set_PolicyInfo(Convert.ToString(ComBoxBranchName.SelectedItem.Text),
                               "DEPT_06",
                               TxtPolicyNo.Text,
                               Convert.ToString(ComBoxPolicyType.SelectedItem.Text),
                               Convert.ToDateTime(TxtPolicyDate.Text), Convert.ToString(ComBoxAccNametst.Text),
                               Convert.ToDouble(TxtPlcyAmt.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtIssueFee.Text),
                               Convert.ToDouble(TxtSprvisionFee.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtTransFee.Text),
                               Convert.ToInt32(TxtDiscountPER.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtDiscountAMT.Text),
                               Convert.ToDouble(TxtTotalAmt.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtNetAmt.Text),
                               DateTime.ParseExact(TextStartDate.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                               DateTime.ParseExact(TxtEndDate.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                               'A',
                               DateTime.ParseExact("20042012", "dd/MM/yyyy", null), "DEVP");
```

Comment: Change 20042012 to 20122004.

Comment: Where does it error? What have you tried/researched? `Text.ToString()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `ParseExact`, your string needs to match your format string *exactly*. This means that the separators also need to be there.

So I see two options:

**1. Pass the date using the appropriate format**

```
 bool flag = gh.Set_PolicyInfo(Convert.ToString(ComBoxBranchName.SelectedItem.Text), "DEPT_06", TxtPolicyNo.Text, Convert.ToString(ComBoxPolicyType.SelectedItem.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(TxtPolicyDate.Text), Convert.ToString(ComBoxAccNametst.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtPlcyAmt.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtIssueFee.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtSprvisionFee.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtTransFee.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TxtDiscountPER.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtDiscountAMT.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtTotalAmt.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtNetAmt.Text),DateTime.ParseExact(TextStartDate.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), DateTime.ParseExact(TxtEndDate.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 'A', DateTime.ParseExact("20/04/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", null), "DEVP");
```

**2. Remove the separators from the format string**

```
 bool flag = gh.Set_PolicyInfo(Convert.ToString(ComBoxBranchName.SelectedItem.Text), "DEPT_06", TxtPolicyNo.Text, Convert.ToString(ComBoxPolicyType.SelectedItem.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(TxtPolicyDate.Text), Convert.ToString(ComBoxAccNametst.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtPlcyAmt.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtIssueFee.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtSprvisionFee.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtTransFee.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TxtDiscountPER.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtDiscountAMT.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtTotalAmt.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TxtNetAmt.Text),DateTime.ParseExact(TextStartDate.Text.ToString(), "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), DateTime.ParseExact(TxtEndDate.Text.ToString(), "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 'A', DateTime.ParseExact("20042012", "ddMMyyyy", null), "DEVP");
```

Comment: Can you please show us values for `TxtPolicyDate.Text`, `TextStartDate.Text` and `TxtEndDate.Text`?

Comment: TxtPolicyDate.Text = 29/04/2015  , TextStartDate.Text = 20/05/2015 and TxtEndDate.Text = 19/05/2016

Comment: Try specifying the culture when using `Convert.ToDateTime()`. Use `CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");` and pass it as second parameter to `Convert.ToDateTime()`